# KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME' in pyspark

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-spark, pyspark

when I try:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc=SparkContext()
```

I get:

```
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'
```

What is the solution?

Comment: set environment variable `SPARK_HOME`

Answer (score 3):

`pyspark` relies on the [spark](https://spark.apache.org/) SDK. You need to have that installed before using `pyspark`.

Once that's set you need to set the environment variable `SPARK_HOME` to tell `pyspark` where to look for your `spark` installation. If you're on a *nix system you can do so by adding the follow to your `.bashrc`

```
export SPARK_HOME=<location of spark install>
```

If you're using Windows there's a convoluted way of setting variables via GUI [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). Through DOS you can use `set` in the place of `export`:

```
SET SPARK_HOME=<location of spark install>
```